# Android: Give any color to an image with some method similar to webkit mask

Tags: android, colors, mask

My partner and I want to give dynamic color to an icon in our Android app (png image with transparent background) in a similar way to webkit mask in CSS:

```
<div style="background-color: #34daa1; width: 60px; height: 60px; -webkit-mask-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZvK4.png');"></div>
```

We think this would be much better than adding an image for each color... :(
Is it possible?

Thank you very much...

Comment: try android:tint="#234233"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying colors to images can be a little tricky as the platform will try to be efficient for you. When you add multiple images that all have the same resource the platform will only hold one reference to the image and point multiple views to it. This can be problematic in cases like ListViews where you might have an image button that is enabled or greyed out based on some data in the adapter item. If you had a view with ten copies of the same image and you modify the image all ten are changes since they reference the same resource under the covers. To combat this you mutate the Drawable when needed to guarantee you get a clean copy.

Here is a good article on the subject from Romain Guy at Google.

http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/

Also, here is an example of how I use mutations to apply color filters on top of images

```
/**
 * Applies a specified color filter to a Drawable.
 *
 * @param drawable drawable to filter.
 * @param color    color to apply.
 * @return a mutated Drawable.
 */
private static Drawable applyColorFilter(Drawable drawable, int color) {
    Drawable mutate = drawable.mutate();
    mutate.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    return mutate;
}
```

So to apply a grayscale filter you would do something like this:

```
/**
 * Applies a color filter to a Drawable.
 *
 * @return a mutated version of the given drawable with a color filter
 * applied.
 */
public static Drawable convertToGrayScale(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return applyColorFilter(drawable, Color.LTGRAY);
}
```

Comment: We'll try it and then I'll validate the best solution for us. Thank you @Matt T.

Comment: A very interesting article! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
img.setBackgroundColor(R.color.gray);
```

You need a picture with transparent background.

**EDIT**

My bad.
Try this

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId)
            .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.drawColor(R.color.gray);
canvas.drawBitmap(bm, left, top, paint);
BitmapDrawable picture = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
```

Comment: Thank you but... it will bring a color to the transparent background, not to the image itself... I think. What we want is to change the color of the image not to the background. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: In your answer you take a HTML example who fill the background of a div not at the image itself ;).
But I have edit my post :)

Comment: Excuse me, maybe you haven't read the entire code... The method use background-color, but it is combined with -webkit-mask-image that fills the image with the background-color set on the style, keeping the transparency of the background. You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dz3hd/
Thanks for your response. We'll try it. :)